# Use local python to run python script from shared drive

Tags: python-2.7, command-line

I am working on a Windows machine with admin rights and Python 2.7. I would like to use my locally downloaded python to call a script on the shared drive from the command line.

Unfortunately, this is not working

`C:\python27\python.exe net use S:file_path\python_script.py`

What is the right way to call a shared python script but run it with a local copy of python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the the \\ after the mapped drive letter. I have a shared drive mapped locally on my windows machine under Z. When I run my local python interpreter and give the above shared path, it works as expected.

For your example, it should be:

`C:\path\to\python\python.exe s:\\file_path\python_script.py`

My example

`C:\Users\david.mcmahon>python z:\\Test\hooks\my_app.py
Running from shared drive..`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, "\\" is what I was missing. Thanks!